Change selected tab item color in TabView without using .tint or .accentColor
.tint and .accentColor affect WAY more than just the tab bar and seeps into toggles, navigation bar button items, sliders, etc., and it seems like a giant pain to set every single component accent individually to avoid this. How can I change the selected item color without affecting any other components?
I've tried setting .foregroundColor/.foregroundStyle on the tab item views (doesn't work).
I also tried setting this in the init with no appreciable effect:
init {
    let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
    tabBarAppearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
    tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.iconColor = UIColor.red
    tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
    tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.iconColor = UIColor.lightGray
    tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray]
    UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance
    UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance
}

I'd prefer not using a custom made tab bar in an overlay if possible. Is there any way to achieve this in the native tab bar without changing the colors of any other component?

Your code works for me on an iPhone simulator running iOS 17.4.

How about doing the same thing but with SwiftUI-Introspect?

So, very interestingly, i was using a 17.0.1 simulator.  Switching to 17.4 the first index is red, but every other index is blue.   Are all of your indexs red as you tap them?
I thought about introspect, but id prefer to not add a dependency.  I do have this working by dropping down to UIKit and using a UIViewControllerRepresentable but i was prefering to do it a pure swiftui way.

Every tab is red for me.

I probably do not understand the question, but using foregroundStyle(...)
for a system image, eg Image(systemName: "globe") in the tabItem works for me, it changes the color when tapped. I can show my test code if you want.

Im using custom images and not system images.  the custom images are set to template image, so the rendering mode should allow the change.

One rather hacky way is to use an image drawn by this initialiser as the tab's icon. During drawing, you can then decide what color you want the icon to be.
    @State var selection = 0
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            List {Text("Foo")}
                .tabItem {
                    Image(size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 60)) { gc in
                        gc.draw(Text(Image(systemName: "globe")).foregroundStyle(selection == 0 ? .red : Color.gray), at: .init(x: 20, y: 15), anchor: .center)
                        gc.draw(Text("Tab 1").foregroundStyle(selection == 0 ? .red : Color.gray), at: .init(x: 20, y: 45), anchor: .center)
                    }
                }
                .tag(0)
            Text("Bar")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 60)) { gc in
                        gc.draw(Text(Image(systemName: "circle")).foregroundStyle(selection == 1 ? .red : Color.gray), at: .init(x: 20, y: 15), anchor: .center)
                        gc.draw(Text("Tab 2").foregroundStyle(selection == 1 ? .red : Color.gray), at: .init(x: 20, y: 45), anchor: .center)
                    }
                }
                .tag(1)
        }
    }


This doesnt seem to have an appreciable affect for me in iOS 17.  the selected color remains blue.  Does this work for you?

@thesuffering Yes, on iOS 17.4.

i tried this, ends up clipped and floating partially outside the tabbar.  im guessing messing with the x and y could probably dial it in better.

@thesuffering Yeah, you would need to do some hardcoding. You can move the image around by creating a larger image, but leaving some parts of the image blank. For example, to move the icon downwards, draw a taller image, e.g. 40100, but leave the top 40 points blank. Draw in the bottom 4060 area.
