How to change icon's color of selected tab bar item without .tint being applied to all sub views in SwiftUI?
Now that .accentColor is going to be deprecated, .tint is proposed like the option but I notice all my toggles inside the tabBar are tinted!
@State private var selectedTab = "One"
@State private var isOn = true
    var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
        VStack{
            Text("Tab 1")
            Toggle(isOn: $isOn){
                Text("Whatever?")
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .tabItem {
            Label("One", systemImage: "star")
        }
        .tag("One")

        Text("Tab 2")
            .tabItem {
                Label("Two", systemImage: "square")
            }
            .tag("Two")
    }
    .tint(.teal)
}



You probably need to apply a preferred tint to each of the child views of the TabView.

@BenzyNeez it's a big proyect I don't think that is a good sloution.

You only have to apply the tint to the parent view of each child in the TabView, it doesn't matter how elaborate the views actually are.

@BenzyNeez .green tint for the toggles to the parent view of each child in the TabView? What if the views use other swiftUI native elements? I would have to apply every one of this element its own tint, right?

See https://stackoverflow.com/q/78451276/5133585

@Sweeper thanks! Saw it but also don't have an acceptable answer yet.

Another way to change the accent color of the TabView is to define an AccentColor in your asset catalog. Then you don't need to set a .tint on the TabView:

The accent color gets used for the active tab of the TabView and also for buttons in subviews, but it does not override the default accent color for a toggle:
var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
        VStack{
            Text("Tab 1")
            Toggle(isOn: $isOn){
                Text("Whatever?")
            }
            Button("A button") {}
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }
        .padding()
        .tabItem {
            Label("One", systemImage: "star")
        }
        .tag("One")

        Text("Tab 2")
            .tabItem {
                Label("Two", systemImage: "square")
            }
            .tag("Two")
    }
    // .tint(.teal)
}



Thanks! but Im using several different colors not just one.

@Fran Another simple solution would be to abandon TabView and just use a ZStack as the container for the views with a custom tab bar for switching.

It's a good alternative! Thanks!

Because all views in the TabView are nested inside it, the tint applied to the TabView applies to the views inside it because they are its children.
